# List element comparison by iteration over it

Tags: list

1.Three lists a, b and c. If a[index] is in b[index] then get the element in list c corresponding to list b[index]. That is if a[0]=b[1],get c[1]:

```
    a = ['ASAP','WTHK']
    b = ['ABCD','ASAP','EFGH','HIJK']
    c = ['1','2','3','4','5']
```

Comment: Unclear what you are talking about. Atleast take some time to think, prepare and then type the question.

Comment: can you show us your efforts before?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: I would use some kind of Map or Dictionary, depending on your platform, programming language. The values in array _b_ as key and values in array _c_ as value of your Map. So you can get the value of _c_ by passing the value of _a_ as key to the Map.

Comment: What should be the behavior if there is no transitive relation from _a_ to _c_ over _b_?

Comment: How would it be done in Python language.?

Comment: ok, need some time to refresh my python, but there is a [dictionary data structure](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in python.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you were looking for. You can add the *b* and the corresponding *c* value to the dictionary in a loop if the *a* array contains the  *b* value. After that you can get the *c* value by *a* value as key like in the code below.

```
a = ['ASAP','WTHK']
#                    b        c 
dictionary_trans = {'ASAP' : '1'}
dictionary_trans = {'WTHK' : '1337'}
# etc. put all b values existing in a to the dict 
# with thier coresponding c values.

key = a[0]
c_value = dictionary_trans.get(key)

print c_value
```

My python skills are very limited, but I think I would try to solve the problem this way.
This solution could crash if you use an *a* value which is not contained in the dictionary, so you need to implement some logic to handle missing relations between *a* and *c*, like insert dummy entries to the dictionary or so.